# Use function pointer with void in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I want to make a structure similar to course registration in C. For this, I used struct instead of the table.

```
STUDENT *createStudent(){
    return (STUDENT *) malloc(sizeof(STUDENT));
}

TEACHER *createTeacher(){
    return (TEACHER *) malloc(sizeof(TEACHER));
}

COURSE *createCourse(){
    return (COURSE *) malloc(sizeof(COURSE));
}

COURSEREGISTRATION *createCourseRegistration(){
    return (COURSEREGISTRATION *) malloc(sizeof(COURSEREGISTRATION));
}
```

I want to pass these functions to a variable with a function pointer. Like;

```
void *createNode(int choise){
    void (*fp[]) () = {createStudent, createTeacher, createCourse, createCourseRegistration};
    return (fp[choise] ());
}
```

I want to do **malloc** with **func pointers** and get an error in this function (main func);

```
STUDENT *studentHead = NULL;
void *temp = studentHead;
temp = createNode(0);//Zero for student
```

*I dont understood func pointers clearly. What should I do? Where did I wrong? or can I use func pointer in this situation?*

THX

EDIT:
I solved the problem like this;

```
#define CREATESTUDENT 0
#define CREATETEACHER 1
#define CREATEDCOURSE 2
#define CREATECOURSEREGISTRATION 3

void createNode(void **temp, int choise){
    switch(choise){
        case CREATESTUDENT:
            *temp = (STUDENT *) malloc(sizeof(STUDENT));
            break;
        case CREATETEACHER :
            *temp = (TEACHER *) malloc(sizeof(TEACHER));
            break;
        case CREATEDCOURSE :
            *temp = (COURSE *) malloc(sizeof(COURSE));
            break;
        case CREATECOURSEREGISTRATION :
            *temp = (COURSEREGISTRATION *) malloc(sizeof(COURSEREGISTRATION ));
            break;
    }
}
```

and used call func;

```
STUDENT *temp = studentHead;
createNode(&temp, CREATESTUDENT);
```

Comment: what error you get

Comment: The functions have to have return type `void *` in order to be used the way you use them in `createNote`

Comment: You might find [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) interesting.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland [Error] void value not ignored as it ought to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: your function ptr signature is `void ()` and not `void* ()`

> happily celebrating c++ does not care that much about function return types :)

TL;DR;

**Why make life harder than they need to be?**
why not use simple switch

```cpp
void *createNode(int choice){
  switch(choice){
    case 0:
      return createStudent();
    case 1:
      return createTeacher();
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

> Note: I don't see the point of creating `createNode` from the first place. it seems misleading signature, and i'd make the API user call `createStudent`, `createTeacher`, etc explicitly.

Some coding style suggestions:

- typedef your function signature
- declare your function array (better as member or static to the module)

Comment: you are absolutely right but I am trying something different(using func pointers) in this tutorial but i guess i cant :)

Answer (score 2):

You declare `fp` as {

```
void (*fp[]) () = {
```

which is an array of pointers to functions returning void.  You want functions that return pointers, so you want

```
void *(*fp[])() = {
```

but then you still have the problem that the function pointers you are using to initialize this array are the wrong type -- they are all functions that return pointers to a real type (not void).  So while this will *probably* work, it is actually undefined behavior as far as the standard is concerned.

If you change all your `create` functions to return `void *` instead of `STUDENT *` (and similar), then it would be safe.

Answer (score -3):

According to your code, `fp` is a `void`, not a `void*` function. You are always returning nothing from `createNode` regardless of `choice`.

Comment: he is returning `void*` its just written in a convention as `void *createNode()` like variable declarations can be `int* pInt` or `int *pInt`

Comment: @TomerW No, he most definitely is not; as you can hopefully see, `fp` is a function pointer array to functions of type `void`. Whenever you call a function dereferenced from fp, it will return `void`, which he is eventually returning from `createNode`.

Comment: my bad, thought you meant the `createNode` function itself.. (so i dont see why it is downvoted)